# Why Intelli J Idea community edition 19.2.1 not showing any thing on maven respotory?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have recently installed Intelli J Idea 19.2.1 community edition. 
I was trying to create maven project but it is not showing anything in dependency list when trying to click on add maven dependency.

I checked the settings at File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Repositories 
but found list is empty and no option to add anything, see attached screen shot.

[image]

Can someone please suggest how can I add maven local and remote repository path to Intelli J Idea community edition 19.2.1 shown below?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219426.
Please follow it for updates.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with y.bedrov

[release notes has listed bug](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2019.2+Release+%28192.5728.98+build%29+Release+Notes)

[image]